# Video Streaming?

Tags: video-streaming

I am building a website in perl where I am showing some videos of our company. I want these videos users can only see... can not download.

What should I use for this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [Longtail](http://www.longtailvideo.com/) player and encoding your videos to FLV.

Or, upload them to YouTube and embed them.

Comment: @ polemon:I guess youtube option is not the good one,in case user wants to change video he would require make lots of changes,but yes Opensource Player is a good option

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure that my answer will be 100% helpful for you but it's the only thing that comes to my head.download a free version of this [video to flash converter pro](http://www.geovid.com/Video_to_Flash_Converter_Pro) and just convert some video file to flash. this tool will generate an html code with control buttons (play, pause, stop) and then you can use Open source Player as you want.
Some list of OpenSource player:
1)[osflv](http://www.osflv.com/Download.html)
2)[FlowPlayer](http://flowplayer.org)
3)[Gnash](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnash/)
4)[OS Player](http://www.osflv.com/Download.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that any video which a user can see may be downloaded - every major browser which exists (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Internet Explorer) has utilities which may used to download streaming videos. Even if one did not exist, it would be simple to record and write the video manually by means of screen capture utilities.

Comment: Agree with your point,now a days there are so many freely available Plugins are there which makes all possible to capture the things

Answer (score 0):

The JW FLV Player is the Internet's most popular and flexible media player. It supports playback of any format the Adobe Flash Player can handle (FLV, MP4, MP3, AAC, JPG, PNG and GIF). It also supports RTMP, HTTP, live streaming, various playlists formats, a wide range of settings and an extensive javascript API.

The skinning functionality allows you to completely customize its look and its plugin architecture allows you to easily extend the player with features such as sharing, recommendations, searching, analytics and ad serving. 
Installation

This section details a step-by-step process of how to install the JW FLV Player onto your page. The download ZIP contains everything you need to get started. 
Step 1: Transfer the player.swf and swfobject.js file from the ZIP to your website. (Make sure that you've also uploaded all the necessary videos / songs / pictures to your site.)
 
Step 2: Embed the player in your HTML page with the lines of code below. Note: If you place the files in different directories, make sure to set the references in this code accordingly.

```
<p id='preview'> The player will show in this paragraph </ p> 

<script type='text/javascript' src='swfobject.js'> </ script> 
<script type='text/javascript'> 
var s1 = new SWFObject ( 'player.swf', 'player','400 ','300','9 '); 
s1.addParam ( 'allowfullscreen', 'true'); 
s1.addParam ( 'allowscriptaccess',' always'); 
s1.addParam ( 'FlashVars',' file = video.flv '); 
s1.write ( 'preview'); 
</ script>
```

[Check the Source](http://forums.techarena.in/technology-internet/1204819.htm)